# django/postgres error:'database XX does not exist'

Tags: django, postgresql, pgadmin

I created a database using pgAdmin GUI tool to use with postgres for my django project. There are only two databases in pgAdmin, the default 'postgres' db you get out of the box with pgAdmin, and my new database, dbfunk.

I'm using django and added postgres as my database and gave the necessary info in settings.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dbfunk',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXX',
        'HOST': 'localhost'
    }
}
```

But when I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

it gives the error, the database 'dbfunk' does not exist, even though it's in both settings.py in Django and added in pgAdmin. The full text of the error is:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "dbfunk" does not exist
```

I've installed the adaptor psycopg2. I also tried `'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',` in Settings.py but this didn't make any difference.

Is there something else I am missing?

When I ran the command psql \u it is only showing the postgres database there also, and not this new database 'dbfunk'.

I don't know if this helps, but upon installing postgres, I was given 5433 in the prompt as the port number.

UPDATE: I just ran `createdb dbfunk` from command line and that seems to have created it as I can now run `python manage.py makemigrations`. But why did I need to do that when I had already done this in pgAdmin? That is, why did I have to create it twice? Is this usual?

UPDATE2: Sadly the database dbfunk that I created from command line using createdb and the dbfunk in pgAdmin are not synchronised and migrations won't carry over, such that I don't see the tables for the django models in pgAdmin.

I installed Postgres initially using Homebrew, and pgAdmin separately but then it didn't provide the default server/database on pgAdmin so I deleted pgAdmin, and uninstalled Postgres, and then downloaded Postgres from the website instead, and it seems that installs pgAdmin alongside it because then when I opened pgAdmin it had the default server/db postgres. I am on macOS, 10.14.6.

When I check ports on 5432 I get this:

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 16337 me    5u  IPv4 0x7560dce8e7fXXXX      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 16337 me   6u  IPv6 0x7560dce8d2XXXXX      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

And on 5433 there are more entries:

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 16809 postgres    4u  IPv6 0x7560dce8e883ed93      0t0  TCP *:pyrrho (LISTEN)
postgres 16809 postgres    5u  IPv4 0x7560dce8e46dXXXX      0t0  TCP *:pyrrho (LISTEN)
pgAdmin4 17043   me   20u  IPv4 0x7560dce8e74cXXXx      0t0  TCP localhost:56820->localhost:pyrrho (ESTABLISHED)
pgAdmin4 17043   me   21u  IPv4 0x7560dce8e74cXXXX       0t0  TCP localhost:57054->localhost:pyrrho (ESTABLISHED)
postgres 17051 postgres   12u  IPv4 0x7560dce8e74cXXXX       0t0  TCP localhost:pyrrho->localhost:56820 (ESTABLISHED)
postgres 17217 postgres   12u  IPv4 0x7560dce8e74cXXXX       0t0  TCP localhost:pyrrho->localhost:57054 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: makemigrations does creating, altering, droping table, not creating database, unless you used sqlite3.

Comment: Yes, it was when I ran this command that I discovered the database was missing.

Comment: When you down loaded the second time what link did you follow to get the Postgres software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you did not specify `PORT`  in `DATABASES`. The default port for postgres is 5432, so if your database cluster that contained dbfunk was listening on port 5433 then Django would not find it. My guess is you  have two instances of postgres running, one on port 5432 and the other on 5433. When you did `createdb dbfunk` I'm guessing you again did not specify a port and the database was created in the cluster listening on 5432. Now `python manage.py makemigrations` could find it using the settings in `DATABASES`.

Comment: I added  'PORT': '5432' in Settings but when I ran python manage.py makemigrations again it said no changes detected. How can I close down 5433 and make 5432 the default? I did migrate as well, then went to pgAdmin, and the tables had not carried over so it definitely is not syncing with the createdb I ran where I did create the database.

Comment: I ran sudo lsof -i tcp:5433 and for 5432 but nothing changed after I then did makemigrations again from Django app. Do I need to do something else?

Comment: So did lsof show Postgres servers running on 5432 and 5433? What OS and version? How did you install Postgres? Can you connect to the server(5432/5433) using psql?

Comment: I installed Postgres initially using Homebrew, and pgAdmin separately but then it didn't provide the default server/database on pgAdmin so I deleted pgAdmin, and uninstalled Postgres, and then downloaded Postgres from the website instead, and it seems that installs pgAdmin alongside it because then when I opened pgAdmin it had the default server/db postgres. I am on macOS, 10.14.6.

Comment: Yep it showed the servers running. On 5432: COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 16337 me    5u  IPv4 0x7560dce8e7f5XXXX      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres 16337 me    6u  IPv6 0x7560dce8d26cXXXX     0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)

Comment: Please add the new information to your question in a formatted form so it will be easier to understand. When you say two servers you mean one listening on 5432 and one listening on 5433, correct?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, I meant to say 2 listening in 5433 and the rest established. I just updated my question with the tables formatted properly. thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright, so now you need to figure out where or if Django put the tables. Using psql connect to the 5432 and the 5433 instances and do ```\l``` to list the database installed in that cluster. If dbfunk is listed connect to it and do ```\d``` to see the tables installed.

Comment: What command should i use to connect to the port instances? I used \connect but this seems to connect to a database. I then did \connect dbfunk and it didn't list the tables, just all four databases. I had tried --port=5432 and then \l but this too gave me back the list of databases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217258/discussion-between-adrian-klaver-and-cheznead).